# Using <hgroup> is this markup valid?

Tags: html

Can hgroup be used like this:

```
<hgroup>
<h3 class="social-facebook">follow us on facebook</h3>
<a href="#" class="go">go</a>
</hgroup>
```

Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really correct usage of hgroup.

http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/ Gives some good examples of how it's meant to be used

Answer (score 1):

[According to W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hgroup.html) hgroup is supposed to contain h1-h6 elements only. You can validate it [here](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2013, nothing is valid use of hgroup because `<hgroup>` is [being dropped](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-hgroup-element-dropped/) from the HTML5 spec.